# Haskell: function that matches any datatype to tuple

Tags: haskell

im looking for a function that takes any datatype, matched only tuples and throws an error if input is no tuple. My idea is something like this:

```
transformTuple :: t -> (a,b)
transformTuple (a,b) = (a,b)
transformTuple _ = error "no tuple"
```

this doesnt work because in line 2 (a,b) is matched with t, with clearly doesnt work.

Comment: This looks as an XY problem: where are you going to use this thing?

Comment: Im just learing haskell, im fiddling around to test my understanding.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend you pretend there's no solution to the task above. A key feature of Haskell (and many other languages) is that types are erased at runtime. If a function has type `f :: t -> ...` it can _not_ inspect type `t`, since at runtime there is no information about that. This improves performance (no need to keep type info around), and ensures a strong theoretical property called parametricity (ignore this for now).

Comment: Cool thanks ! thats the information i need ! and when empty argument is possible i use maybe?

Comment: What is an "empty argument"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you are doing this wrong and if done correctly you would not *need* such a function. Note that you are replacing a *type-check error* with run-time error.

That said, you may implement that using type classes, and if there is enough context for type inference (or if you add the type annotations):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Tuple a b c where
    tuple :: a -> Maybe (b, c)

instance Tuple a b c where
    tuple _ = Nothing

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Tuple (a, b) a b where
    tuple = Just
```

then:

```
\> let a@(b, _) = (42 :: Int, 3.14 :: Double)
\> tuple a :: Maybe (Int, Int)
Nothing
\> tuple b :: Maybe (Int, Double)
Nothing
\> tuple a :: Maybe (Int, Double)
Just (42,3.14)
```